# How to say......" Focus and Persevere"..in classic latin

Tags: classical-latin

I am creating a motto on an emblem, and I want to use that  phrase.....Focus and Perservere.....in Latin as my motto. Hence the need for the phrase in classic Latin.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please take a look at [these instructions for asking a translation question](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/483/79) and edit your question to add details.

Answer (score -1):

The "persevere" part has been discussed in [a recent post](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/15579/looking-for-the-most-accurate-translation-of-remember-and-persevere). For "focus," the verb *animadvertere* comes to mind (= *animum advertere*). So perhaps *Animadvertito atque obdura*.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you change tenses in the imperatives?

Comment: Animadvertito sounds better to me than -verte. The categorization as "future" imperative is, in my mind, rather theoretical.